# Create ISO files for each folder

Tags: windows, iso

I have 30-40 folders with files and folders within:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
…
```

I want to create an ISO files for each folder like so:

```
folder1.iso
folder2.iso
folder3.iso
…
```

I’m using [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/) on Windows, but I can’t find this feature.

I’m creating ISO files one by one and the operation is very long.

Comment: You *might* get better answers over at [SU](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are basically looking for a way to create an ISO File on command line. Since you have PowerIso, you can use [piso](http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/create-iso-file-on-command-line.htm), which is PowerISO command line utility located in PowerISO installation directory.

> PowerISO can not only creates ISO image file on Window GUI, but it
>   also can creates ISO file on Windows command line. You can find
>   piso.exe which is PowerISO command line utility in PowerISO
>   installation directory.
>
> Usage: piso  [parameters] [-switches]
>
> create:  Create iso file from files or folders.
>
> Example: Create d:\test.iso from d:\test and d:\test.zip.
>
> Command: `piso create -o d:\test.iso -add d:\test / -add d:\test.zip
>   /`
>
> - -o:  Specify output image file name.
> - -ot : Specify output image file type. If not specified, the image type will be determined by file name suffix.
> - -add  : Add local file or directory to image file.
> - -volsize : Split output image file to multiple volumes, and set volume size to . Example: -volsize 100M
> - -setpassword : Set password for output image file.   Example: -setpassword 12345678
> - -label :  Set volume label for output image file.  Example: -label BACKUP
> - -joliet <1|2|3>:  Set joliet level for output image file.  Example: -joliet 3
> - -udf :  Enable or disable UDF option for output image file.  Example: -udf on
> - -iso-name-len <12|30|221>:  Set iso9660 file name length for output image file.  Example: -iso-name-len 221
> - -joliet-name-len <64|110>:  Set joliet file name length for output image file.  Example: -joliet-name-len 110
> - -allow-lower-case-iso-name:  Allow lower case iso9660 file name for output image file.
> - -disable-optimization:  Disable file space optimization for output image file.
> - -file-datetime :  Set file date time for output image file.  Example: -file-datetime 12-20-2008-08:00:00
> - -vol-creation-datetime :  Set volume creation date time for output image file.
> - -vol-modification-datetime :  Set volume modification date time for output image file.
> - -vol-effective-datetime :  Set volume effective date time for output image file.
> - -vol-expiration-datetime :  Set volume expiration date time for output image file.
> - -comment:  Set comment for output image file.
> - -comment-from-file :  Load comment from the file.

Comment: mmm..but commands above is valid only for a single folder. But i have 30-40 folders

Comment: @user332153 You'll need to loop through your directories, e.g. http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

Comment: for example, inside C:\test i have 30-40 folders that i want convert into ISOs. Which command can u suggest me? `for /d`is for parent folders present in a directory? because there is also `for /d /r` but i don't want recurse into subfolders.

Comment: Don't make it more difficult than it is: 'dir > doit.bat' on the command line, then edit doit.bat and run it. No need to build loops in a batch file, *unless* you do this repeatedly with a varying number of folders.

Comment: Command right for ONE folder is `piso create -o C:\test\File.iso -add C:\test\File.iso /` but for more of 1 folder? I can't use a batch because i must have to extract names folders.

Answer (score 2):

here is an untested quick set of commands for windows xp commandline.

instructions to use:

1. open a command prompt
2. change to root directory or drive (i.e - directory above folder 1, folder2, folder3 etc)
3. copy and paste below commands

   *set piso="%programfiles%\poweriso\piso.exe"*
   *for /f "usebackq" %a in (`dir /b /ad`) do %piso% create -o d:\%a.iso -add d:\%a*

please make sure the path in variable %piso% to piso.exe is correct.
if running from a batch script %a needs to become %%a.

edited cos comments arent nicely formatted for readability

hi @user332153 - looks like the below line is fine then:

*set piso="%programfiles%\poweriso\piso.exe"*

the backticks were removed from dir /b /ad - if the backticks dont show, it is not a quotation mark, it is the key with a tilde ~ on it.

lets see if we can write this all up then:

*set piso="%programfiles%\poweriso\piso.exe"*

*cd a*

*for /f "usebackq" %a in (`dir /b /ad`) do %piso% create -o d:\%a.iso -add d:\%a*

this should create one.iso and two.iso from directories one and two.

Comment: error http://imageshack.com/a/img661/3735/d96OR0.png  I have piso.exe in `C:\Program Files\PowerISO\piso.exe`while i have create a folder called `a` in C:\ Inside `a` folder i have 2 folder (one, two) that i want convert into ISO. Can u fix your command, please?

Comment: @user332153 - please see amended answer

Comment: i try follow your commands but something is wrong..look this pic, please: http://imageshack.com/a/img537/6500/tDpk6k.png Seems no give error but it give no action! ISO can't be created, i don't understand why. PS: but why `d:\%a.iso` if my path is in `C` and if inside folder a i have more one folder?

Comment: hi - run the commands starting from the c:\ drive root in the command prompt. the `cd a` command will change to the `a` directory, the `for` loop will then loop through directories a and b.
%a is a variable for the directory names given as output by the command `dir /b /ad`, run in C:\a.

Comment: `Bad parameter: -add` http://imageshack.com/a/img537/579/BeAWSn.png also i had to change piso.exe path because with %programfiles% give me error "path not found". I copy piso.exe into root folder

Comment: make `d:\%a.iso` say `%a.iso` and `d:\%a` say `%a` only. also, you can set piso to the absolute path surrounded by quotes if you need to. sorry, not sure why %programfiles% does not work on your pc.

Comment: I try using your edited command: **for /f "usebackq" %a in (`dir /b /ad`) do %piso% create -o %a.iso -add %a** give me same error: Bad parameter: -add. Can u write me exactly command, please? I want give you best answer!!

Comment: sorry, i'm going off the piso.exe paramteres written above - I have no experience with piso.exe myself. @franckdernoncourt - could you please help?